# VBA - Is there an "on error" statement with an ELSE option?

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA, I need to have two options for using a variable in an excel cell:

1. if there is a value in the cell
2. if there is not a value in the cell

I assume that VBA will give me an error if I tried to read a cell when nothing is in it, so not sure how to do it.

I would like to do something like

```
A=sheet1.cells(1,1).value
on error goto fail

fail:
A=0
' need to continue here, with A from the cell or set to 0
B=A+1
```

Comment: `If sheet1.cells(1,1).value = "" then: A = 0: Else: A= sheet1.cells(1,1).value: End If`

Answer (score 1):

Although Scott's answer in the comment is certainly right I usually take the Len function to check for an empty cell or string

```
If len(A) = 0 then
' do sth
else
' sth else
end if
```

The answer to the other question is: There is no Else for [On Error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/on-error-statement)

Comment: I prefer the `Len()` function as well, as it's less overhead than accessing the string directly, but it is also a good idea to allays check for cell errors before attempting to access its value: `If Not IsError(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)) Then A = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value2`